# Mapear FormGroup em um objeto

Tags: angular, formulário, angular-8

Eu gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma melhor de fazer a atribuição dos valores de um formGroup em um objeto. A baixo segue o que eu fiz, porem acho que assim fica meio estranho, mas tambem não consegui achar outra forma.

```
get t() {
    return travelersForm.controls;
  }
```

Esse é o meu formGroup

```
this.t.push(
  this.formBuilder.group({
    docType: [{ value: 'CPF', disabled: true }],
    document: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, cValidatorCpf])],
    name: ['', Validators.required],
    dateBirth: ['', Validators.required],
    age: [{ value: nAge, disabled: true }],
    email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    phone: ['', Validators.required],
  }, {
    validator: Validators.compose([
      cValidatorAge('dateBirth', 'age', this.travelerService.currentInsuranceValue),
    ])
  })
);
```

Aqui é onde eu estou fazendo a atribuição dos valores do formGroup em um objeto para fazer o post pro back.

```
    setInsuredObj() {
    let insured: Insured;
    insured.id = 0;
    insured.idUser = this.user.idUser;
    insured.typeSex = {id: 1, initials: 'M', description: 'Masculino', code: '1'} as TypeSex;
    insured.document = this.t.controls[0]['controls'].document;
    insured.name = this.t.controls[0]['controls'].name.value;
    insured.birthdate = this.t.controls[0]['controls'].dateBirth.value;
    insured.email = this.t.controls[0]['controls'].email.value;
    insured.zipCode = this.af.zipCode.value;
    insured.address = this.af.address.value;
    insured.number = this.af.number.value;
    insured.complement = this.af.complement.value;
    insured.neighborhood = this.af.neighborhood.value;
    insured.state = this.af.state.value;
    insured.city = this.af.city.value;
    insured.telephone1 = this.t.controls[0]['controls'].phone.value;
  }
```

Eu gostaria de saber se tem uma forma melhor de fazer isso pois eu tenho um formArray que seria meio chato fazer assim "na mao" tambem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um dos meios é usar desestruturação e montar o seu objeto

`const insured = { this.user.userId, typeSex: {id: 1, initials: 'M', description: 'Masculino', code: '1'} as TypeSex, ... }`

você poderia atribuir isso a um método que te retorne o objeto "mapeado"

```
mapearObjetos(): Insured {
  for (let item of this.t) {
     transformObjeto(item); // metodo que retorna objeto usando 
     // desestruturação(Destructuring)
  }
}
```

se tiver vários itens, você vai ter que salvar em uma lista, tem outros meios de fazer, segue a referência para usar desestruturação.

[destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao)

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado pela ajuda vou dar uma olhada nisso